# How do I check if checkbox is checked in PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox

I am trying to check if a checkbox have been checked in PHP in order to register. But it's not working right now. This is the code I am using so far, to check if it have been checked.

```
if(!isset($_POST['tos']))
  $this->errors[] = 'Please accept our Terms of Service.';
```

And this is the HTML code.

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="tos" value="0"> I agree to the <a href="#">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
</label>
</div>
```

Full form code:

```
        <form role="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
              <div class="form-group">

              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname">
                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ruser" name="ruser" placeholder="Username">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email2">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="remail" name="remail" placeholder="Enter email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label for="password2">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="rpass" name="rpass" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label for="password2">Repeat password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="rpass2" name="rpass2" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="tos" value="0"> I agree to the <a href="#">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                </label>
              </div>
               <input type="hidden" name="secur" value="<?php echo $ip;?>"/>
               <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token;?>"/>
              <button type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-block btn-color btn-xxl">Create an account</button>
            </form>
```

What's wrong with this code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have a POST form for the HTML? var_dump($_POST);

Comment: Yes, I do have a POST form for the html code.

Comment: can you post the complete form?

Comment: Give some debug out, try to "print_r" your $_POST to see what it has...

Comment: Posted the complete form code now. And I have set the value to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_POST['tos']))
  $this->errors[] = 'Please accept our Terms of Service.';`
```

What this is doing is saying if there is no 'tos' in $_POST, throw an error.

Really you should probably check this client side with javascript, *before* the form is sent to the server.

You could also...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tos" value="accepted" checked>
```

And PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['tos']) && $_POST['tos']==='accepted') echo 'All good'; 
else array_push($errors,'err code here'); //to add to $error array
```

**Update**

I'm not sure if you're using jQuery or not, but just for a more user friendly approach:

```
var tos = $('#tos');
var notice = $('.notice');
tos.on('click',function(){
  if(tos.is(':checked')){
    notice.text('Thank you.');
  }
  else{
   notice.text('Please accept our ToS to continue.');
  }
})
```

[See a working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hGmzm/) You could even halt the form all together if it's unchecked. BTW, if I remember correctly `checkbox` inputs only send POST data *if* checked.

Comment: I tried the code bro, but I'm not sure if it works. I would like it the text into the errors array, if it's not checked. Tried this --> if(isset($_POST['tos']) && $_POST['tos']===1) $this->errors[] = 'All good'; 
 else $this->errors[] = 'ToS was not accepted...'; <--- But it doesn't add it to the errors array. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what setup you have but I think you're taking a JS approach to arrays. If you have `$errors = array()` already in existence, you can add a value using `array_push($errors,'err code here');`. Or even `$errors[0] = 'err code';`, assuming 0 is blank and you don't care to overwrite it every time.

Comment: Seriously though, if you're going to be passing input via POST, I would validate prior to sending with javascript. It would be much more user friendly I would think, rather than hitting submit, having to go back, and possibly losing the data they entered.

Comment: 1) you still have to check with PHP. 2) adding `checked` is a bad advice, I've never seen a single site doing that. 3) `$_POST['tos']===1` won't work, input parameters are strings.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Good point about it passing as a string. I saw 0 in the OP and immediately thought boolean. I've seen plenty of sites with pre-checked ToS. It saves users a step, its there in plain sight, and they have to accept to proceed anyway. You still have to check with PHP - if it's there or not. I still say verify client side 1st, it's just good practice.

Comment: Alright thanks to both of you.