# Return checkbox data and input (if entered) PHP foreach

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, foreach

```
<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 1">
<input type="text" name="answer1" value="" />

<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 3">
<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 4">
<input type="text" name="answer4" value="" />
........................
<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 20">
```

I have a random amount of competitions some of these competitions will have a question which is unique to the specific one.

```
foreach($_POST['competition'] as $value) {
    echo "Value = $value <br>";
}
```

Any checked boxes will return using the above code, but how would I return a text box field which is unique to that competition?

If someone has entered 4 out of the 10 competitions and have answered two questions I would like the data to be displayed like so.

```
comp 1 - answer 1
comp 4 
comp 5
comp 9 - answer 2
```

Comment: ok, but where and how are you displaying/submitting these questions that are related to the checkboxes?

Comment: slightly edited my original post - for the competitions where a input field will be required, it will be right next to the checkbox so literally just <input type="text" name="answer" value="" />

Comment: Try this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050812/how-to-post-an-associative-array-in-php

Comment: Thank you - I've got it to work with just one question and answer but struggling as it always returns the last entry, like it's being over written every time. I'll carry on... persistence! :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368625/how-do-i-check-if-checkbox-is-checked-in-php