# Checking checkbox state and executing PHP query based on it

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have the following checkbox in a table:

```
<td><span id='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='secret' value='true'> Share Anomolously? </span></td>
```

I have altered my PHP code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368625/how-do-i-check-if-checkbox-is-checked-in-php) previous question. I have the following code which executes two different queries based on whether the checkbox is checked or not:

```
$post_msg = @$_POST['msg'];

if (isset($_POST['secret'])=='true' && $post_msg != "" ) {
    // Checkbox is selected
    $posted_info = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
    //$date_of_msg  = date("Y-m-d");
    //$time_of_msg = date("H:i");
    $msg_sent_by  = $username;
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO user_thoughts VALUES ('','$post_msg','','' ,'$attach_name','$msg_sent_by','')";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_query) or die(mysqli_error());
} else if (isset($_POST['secret'])!=='true' && $post_msg != "" ) {
   // Alternate code
    $posted_info = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
    //$date_of_msg  = date("Y-m-d");
    //$time_of_msg = date("H:i");
    $msg_sent_by  = $username;
    $insert_query2 = "INSERT INTO user_thoughts VALUES ('','$post_msg','','' ,'$attach_name','$msg_sent_by','no')";
    $run_query2 = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_query2) ;
}
```

With this current piece of code, when a user hits the button to post their message `$post_msg` and the checkbox is not checked, it inserts `no` in the database, when it shouldn't. Just to explain, the last `''` in the insert query `INSERTS` data to a column called `shared`, and has a defined value of `yes`.

So if the user posts a message, with the checkbox unchecked, it should execute the first if statement. And if the user shares a post with the checkbox checked, it should execute the second if statement which `INSERTS` no in column `shared`.

At the moment, it will always INSERT `no` in the `shared` column, even when the checkbox isn't checked.

Comment: `isset($_POST['secret']) !== 'true'` is always true when unchecked _as the checkbox is not sent when it is  unchecked_. i,e `false !== 'true'`. Use `if (! isset($_POST['secret']) { // checkbox unchecked processing...`

Comment: ahh, I see, worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's because:

```
isset($_POST['secret'])=='true'
```

Is only check to see if it has a value.  It's not checking what they value IS.